# Width transition on ::before element

Tags: css, css-transitions

I facing a CSS issue on a "toogle" element to switch from two differents forms.

As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/7o6mchvn/ the ::before element (who content text) on the left side of the switch, the transition don't go on the right side.

```
#formSwitch li a span::before{content:attr(data-letters); position:absolute; color:#fff; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; width:0%; -webkit-transition: all 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1); transition: all 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1);}
#formSwitch li a.selected span::before{width:100%;}
```

The green part go right, but the text go left.

I can't find how to figure out this issue.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need, Please check the below code, i have added two lines here

```
#switchIngr a span:before{ 
   right:0;
}

#switchHour a span:before { 
   left:0;
}
```

Please check with the snippet

```js
$( "#formSwitch a" ).click(function() {
  $( "#formSwitch a" ).each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){
      $(this).removeClass('selected'); 
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#formRightSide #formSwitch{position:relative; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:.6em; line-height:1.1em;}
#formSwitch li{position:relative; display:inline-block; background:red ; color:#999; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
#formSwitch li#switchIngr{border-top-left-radius:11px; border-bottom-left-radius:11px;}
#formSwitch li#switchHour{border-top-right-radius:11px; border-bottom-right-radius:11px;}
#formSwitch li a{display:inline-block; overflow: hidden; line-height: 1; color: #999; text-decoration:none;}
#formSwitch li#switchIngr a{padding:.6em .6em .6em 1em; border-top-left-radius:11px; border-bottom-left-radius:11px;}
#formSwitch li#switchHour a{padding:.6em 1em .6em .6em; border-top-right-radius:11px; border-bottom-right-radius:11px;}
 
#formSwitch li a::after{content:''; position:absolute; height:100%; width:0%; top:0; z-index:-1; background:#58bb9c; -webkit-transition: width 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1); transition: width 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1);}
#formSwitch li#switchIngr a::after{right:0; border-top-left-radius:11px; border-bottom-left-radius:11px;}
#formSwitch li#switchHour a::after{left:0; border-top-right-radius:11px; border-bottom-right-radius:11px;}
#formSwitch li a.selected::after{width: 100%;}
 
#formSwitch li a span {position:relative; display:block;}
#formSwitch li a span::before{content:attr(data-letters); position:absolute; color:#fff; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; width:0%; -webkit-transition: all 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1); transition: all 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1);}
#formSwitch li a.selected span::before{width:100%;}
#switchIngr a span:before{ right:0;}
#switchHour a span:before { left:0;}
```

```html
<ul id="formSwitch">
  <li id="switchIngr">
    <a href="#" class="selected">
      <span data-letters="ingredient">ingredient</span>
    </a>
  </li><li id="switchHour">
  <a href="#">
    <span data-letters="hour">hour</span>
  </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also check with the fiddle link [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/7o6mchvn/3/)

Comment: I already try this, it's almost the result I looking for but this is not (: The problem is that the all the white word "ingredient" move with the green background. I want him stay at the same place and hide like an overflow (as same the hour is revealed)

Comment: Then what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

```
#formSwitch li a span::before{
    content:attr(data-letters);
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:0%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1);
    transition: all 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1);
}
#formSwitch li:last-child a span::before{
    left:0;
}
#formSwitch li:first-child a span::before{
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, but I already try that and the problem remain. Because de white text on left move with the green box. And I want him stay static a hide/reveal like this http://imgur.com/UjGiKpA

Answer (score 0):

**Updated the css code and i think you are looking for this when the green box move white color text should be shown accordingly. Replace the css code and let me know if this works or you are looking for something else. Also, if you slow down the animation speed from 3s to 7s than you can clearly see the type of animation you are looking for.**

```
#formRightSide #formSwitch{position:relative; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:.6em; line-height:1.1em;}
    #formSwitch li{position:relative; display:inline-block; background:red ; color:#999; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);float:left;margin:0;padding:0;}
    #formSwitch li#switchIngr{border-top-left-radius:11px; border-bottom-left-radius:11px;}
    #formSwitch li#switchHour{border-top-right-radius:11px; border-bottom-right-radius:11px;}
    #formSwitch li a{display:inline-block; overflow: hidden; line-height: 1; color: #999; text-decoration:none;}
    #formSwitch li#switchIngr a{padding:.6em .6em .6em 1em; border-top-left-radius:11px; border-bottom-left-radius:11px;}
    #formSwitch li#switchHour a{padding:.6em 1em .6em .6em; border-top-right-radius:11px; border-bottom-right-radius:11px;}
    #formSwitch li a::after{content:''; position:absolute; height:100%; width:0%; top:0; z-index:-1; background:#58bb9c; -webkit-transition: width 3s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1); transition: width 3s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1);}
    #formSwitch li#switchIngr a::after{right:0; border-top-left-radius:11px; border-bottom-left-radius:11px;}
    #formSwitch li#switchHour a::after{left:0; border-top-right-radius:11px; border-bottom-right-radius:11px;}
    #formSwitch li a.selected::after{width: 100%;}
    #formSwitch li a span {position:relative; display:block;}
    #formSwitch li a.selected span::before{width:100%;}
    #formSwitch li a span::before{
    content:attr(data-letters);
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:0%;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1);
    transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1);
    }
    #formSwitch li a.selected span::before{
    display:none;
    }
    #formSwitch li a span{
    color:#999;
    -moz-transition:all linear 3s;
    -webkit-transition:all linear 3s;
    -ms-transition:all linear 3s;
    -o-transition:all linear 3s;
    transition:all linear 3s;
    }
    #formSwitch li a.selected span{
    color:#fff;
    -moz-transition:all linear 3s;
    -webkit-transition:all linear 3s;
    -ms-transition:all linear 3s;
    -o-transition:all linear 3s;
    transition:all linear 3s;
    }
    #formSwitch li:last-child a span::before{
    left:0;
    }
    #formSwitch li:first-child a span::before{
    right:0;
    }
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for, but it can be a goo alternative to solve the problem ¯\_(ツ)_/¯